# How to extract the firmware from the flash chip of the router?

Tags: embedded, firmware-analysis, router

**Hi, I've been struggling with a subject since 2 weeks.


I have MSS5004W model router from RicherLink. The board is RL-S4005ef. This device has OpenWrt installed but it's not normally supported by that OS. So I think they ported OpenWrt for this device so there are no known firmware on the internet for this device.


I extracted the content of the flash chip into firmware.bin, flash is gd25q127c nor flash.


According to U-Boot output of the router, I have this memory mapping:**

Creating 11 MTD partitions on "spi0.0":
0x000000000000-0x000000030000 : "u-boot"
0x000000030000-0x000000040000 : "u-boot-env"
0x000000040000-0x000000050000 : "Factory"
0x000000050000-0x000000150000 : "kernel"
0x000000150000-0x000000720000 : "rootfs"
mtd: root_zone=0
mtd: partition "rootfs" set to be root filesystem
0x000000720000-0x000000820000 : "kernel2"
0x000000820000-0x000000df0000 : "rootfs2"
0x000000df0000-0x000000ff0000 : "rootfs_data"
0x000000ff0000-0x000001000000 : "vendor"
0x000000050000-0x000000720000 : "firmware"
0x000000720000-0x000000df0000 : "firmware2"

**When I binwalk the .bin file, I get this output:**

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
73680         0x11FD0         U-Boot version string, "U-Boot 1.1.3 (Sep 18 2018 - 16:47:56)"
327696        0x50010         uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x41E8CEF2, created: 2018-10-30 04:57:02, image
size: 965681 bytes, Data Address: 0x88000000, Entry Point: 0x88000000, data CRC: 0x94204675, OS:
Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "MIPS OpenWrt
Linux-2.6.32.27"

327760        0x50050         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2837756
bytes

1376256       0x150000        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:lzma, size: 3359661 bytes, 1572
inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2018-10-30 04:56:57

7471120       0x720010        uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x41E8CEF2, created: 2018-10-30 04:57:02, image
size: 965681 bytes, Data Address: 0x88000000, Entry Point: 0x88000000, data CRC: 0x94204675, OS:
Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "MIPS OpenWrt
Linux-2.6.32.27"

7471184       0x720050        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2837756
bytes

8519680       0x820000        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:lzma, size: 3359661 bytes, 1572
inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2018-10-30 04:56:57

14614528      0xDF0000        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian

16711680      0xFF0000        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:lzma, size: 17055 bytes, 33 inodes,
blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2017-04-25 08:44:25

**It seems like there are 2 firmwares installed, I can confirm this by checking the U-boot output:**

U-Boot 1.1.3 (Sep 18 2018 - 16:47:56)
Board: Ralink APSoC DRAM:  64 MB
relocate_code Pointer at: 83fb8000
enable ephy clock...done. rf reg 29 = 5
SSC disabled.
spi_wait_nsec: 29 
spi device id: c8 40 18 c8 40 (4018c840)
find flash: GD25Q127C
raspi_read: from:30000 len:1000 
raspi_read: from:30000 len:1000 
============================================ 
Ralink UBoot Version: 4.2.1.0 r18163
-------------------------------------------- 
ASIC 7620_MP (Port5<->None)
DRAM component: 512 Mbits DDR, width 16
DRAM bus: 16 bit
Total memory: 64 MBytes
Flash component: 16 MBytes NOR Flash
Date:Sep 18 2018  Time:16:47:56
============================================ 
icache: sets:512, ways:4, linesz:32 ,total:65536
dcache: sets:256, ways:4, linesz:32 ,total:32768 
The CPU freq = 580 MHZ 
estimate memory size =64 Mbytes
raspi_read: from:50010 len:40 
raspi_read: from:720010 len:40 
=================================================
Check image validation:
Image1 Header Magic Number --> OK
Image2 Header Magic Number --> OK
Image1 Header Checksum --> OK
Image2 Header Checksum --> OK
Image1 Data Checksum --> raspi_read: from:50050 len:ebc31 
OK
Image2 Data Checksum --> raspi_read: from:720050 len:ebc31 
OK
Image1 Stable Flag --> Stable
Image1 Try Counter --> 0
Image2 Stable Flag --> Not stable
Image2 Try Counter --> 0
Image1: OK Image2: OK root_zone: 0

**I tried to extract each firmware with dd by taking uImage, LZMA compressed data and Squashfs folder and created .bin files out of them. But to no avail I get "invalid model" error by doing tftp boot, openwrt sysupgrade from root file system or using the web interface to flash the firmware.**

**Does anybody know how can I extract the firmware out of this flash file system? I need urgent help.**

Comment: How did you dump the firmware? "I tried to extract each firmware ..." Was that successful?  What do you want to do? Modify firmware? Why/which parts? How does the new bin file look compared to the old one? If you have serial access and can flash via hardware you could maybe see where and why it fails. Or look for "invalid model" in the firmware and see what is checked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I dumped the firmware using a CH341a spi flash programmer by connecting to the flash rom. Extracting firmwares were successful but I get a lzma compressed file that when I used binwalk it says 'data' and unlzma decompression results in errors. 

That's correct, I want to modify the firmware, pack it back and push into the router again. I have serial access though UART and with usb to uart converter I have, that's how I got the bootloader printout. "invalid model" error doesn't show me the reason. It tries to boot the image and throws "invalid model".

Comment: " Extracting firmwares were successful" contradicts "unlzma decompression results in errors". Or is dumping=extraction in your case? What part do you wan't to modify and why? There might be easier ways when you have serial access.

Comment: Well, to be more clear; I dumped the flash rom to a .bin file. And from this .bin file, I extracted parts that I thought were firmwares, first was image header + lzma compressed data + squashfs file system. I used the dd command to carve the data in the specific address range that the binwalk command shows. I tried extracting into .bin, bin.lzma, lzma, .img. But all of them fails when I try to decompress with "unlzma" or "lzma -d" commands. I also tried flashing them with the tftp flash commands of the U-boot, from the Openwrt sysupgrade or from the interface of the router. None worked so far.